# react-bootstrap-table-next doesn't have type script to support import

Tags: reactjs

After I installed react-bootstrap-table-next, I tried to use 
"import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';" in my tsx file. As example showed in [here](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Pagination&selectedStory=Fully%20Custom%20Pagination&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

I got error message says "Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-bootstrap-table-next'. '../node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type."

And I run npm install @types/react-bootstrap-table-next, but couldn't find any.

Does anyone has same issue? or how did you solve the problem?

Ron

Answer (score 1):

Right now it looks like there are no plans to support Typescript by the team that develop the project.

You can track the develop of the issue here on this [issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap-table/react-bootstrap-table2/issues/384#issuecomment-398786953) and maybe you can vote up. I'm also waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-bootstrap-table-next). There is support for TypeScript now.

```
npm install --save @types/react-bootstrap-table-next
```

or

```
yarn add @types/react-bootstrap-table-next
```

Answer (score -2):

try running 
`npm install react-bootstrap-table-next --save`